# How to make proportional layouts in android?

Tags: android, xml, layout, screen-size

I have a design that I need to follow in my app. In it there are several buttons, images and textviews placed all over the screen (some are aligned to the left, some to the right, some are centered etc). What I need to do is make all those elements appear EXACTLY as they are in the design image. The problem is, if I try to do this using dp, it can be wider or narrower than the design image specifies, and it depends on the properties of the screen. (I've had an app where I did it all in dp, and on my high-res phone it works perfectly, but on my friend's older phone it cuts away the edges of the activity)

My question is, what elements do I use for this? I've heard of using weight in Linear Layouts, but how to make items different width and height and position them all across the screen how I see fit? How to make sure it looks exactly the same on all screen sizes?

Thanks in advance! :)

Edit:

[image: My layout]

The point is, I need the buttons to be just as they are on the screen (this will be a listview element, I'm trying to make an xml for it). The distance, proportion, everything, it needs to scale to the width of the screen and be this size and distribution. And, I'm not just looking for a solution to THIS particular problem, I want to learn how to do it in general...

Comment: I think using weight in your case is a good solution, can you post a small scheme of your design ?

Comment: added an example. It's the image

Comment: You can use Relative Layout. If you don't have any time… you should use  webView, but it's not a good idea, and not conventional. Give us your code pls.

Comment: There isn't any code yet for this app. I'm just starting it now. I used the Relative Layout, but making everything proportional perfectly with RelativeLayout is simply not an option, I think...

Answer (score -1):

You don't.  For very large and very small screens, you use separate layouts that scale the sizes, completely drop parts of the UI, or lays it out in a different manner.  It's absolutely silly to think you can fit all the stuff on a 10 inch tablet and a 3.5 inch phone.  If your designer expects that, tell him he's an idiot and he needs to get back to work.

For a more general answer on the best way of laying things out-  it depends on the effect you're trying to get.  You should never use pixel counts, and dp should only be used for small things-  a bit of padding between 2 fields.  Most things should be done via layout, either by using a linear layout and getting things in rows/columns, or a RelativeLayout and describing how to layout views relative to their siblings.  But even with these tools you will not be able to fit on all screens and look good.